# Posting data from mvc view to a webform in the same MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have an MVC project that needs to use SSRS for reporting. For this reason my MVC project now has a webform that holds  the reportviewer control. From my MVC page I now need to pass certain parameters to the webform. What is the recommended way to do this? I’m not sure I want to use sessions for this purpose unless it is the recommended way. How do I post from the mvc view to the web form? I don’t think I can call it by controller name as the web form has no controller.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I have maintained a legacy system that used the webform for report generated and an ASP.NET MVC in the new pages. I found out only one way to do that is using the Session to communicate between the webform and the ASP.NET MVC pages. So any other approaches will be welcome :)